# Drawing rectangles on a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw, graphics2d

I have a JScrollPane and on top of it I have a JPanel named 'panel1'.
I want some rectangles to be drawn on this JPanel.

I have a class named DrawRectPanel which extends JPanel and does all the drawing stuff.
The problem is that, I tried to draw the rectangles on panel1 by writing the following  code :

```
panel1.add(new DrawRectPanel());
```

but nothing appeared on panel1
then I tried, just as a test to the class DrawRectPanel :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(1000, 500);
Container contentPane =    frame.getContentPane();
contentPane.add(new DrawRectPanel());
frame.show();
```

This worked, and produced the drawings but on a separate JFrame
How can I draw the rectangles on panel1 ?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT :
code for DrawRectPanel

```
public class DrawRectPanel extends JPanel  {

    DrawRectPanel() {
        Dimension g = new Dimension(400,400);
        this.setPreferredSize(g);
        System.out.println("label 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("label 2");
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(20, 10, 80, 30);
    }
 }
```

only label 1 is printed on the screen

Comment: no idea why, please post (edit you question) here code in http://sscce.org/ form

Comment: If you don't show the code for `DrawRectPanel`, there's no chance anybody can really help you. I'd make a guess though: there's no preferred size for DrawRectPanel, is there?

Comment: An SSCCE is far more useful than more code snippets.  Please read the linked article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

still no idea,

for example

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CustomComponent extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomComponent() {
        setTitle("Custom Component Graphics2D");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void display() {
        add(new CustomComponents());
        pack();
        // enforces the minimum size of both frame and component        
        setMinimumSize(getSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomComponent main = new CustomComponent();
        main.display();
    }
}

class CustomComponents extends JComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, the key is that you need to provide a preferred size for the layout managers.

Answer (score 1):

instead of adding

```
contentPane.add(new DrawRectPanel());
```

you should do

```
contentPane.add(panel1);
```

Because you already have new `DrawRectPanel` in panel1. But in your code you are adding another instance of `DrawRectPanel` in `contentPane`. And never added `panel1` in none of your `container`.

Comment: first, i should add panel1 (which overrides paintcomponent function) on a scrollpane, so i should write scrollpane.add(panel1) , if i do this, only the constructor of panel1 is called and not the paintcomponent function itself, do you know why ?

Comment: you can manually call paintcomponent by   panel1.repaint();panel1.validate();

Answer (score 0):

to fix your problem, change "paintComponent" to "paint" when the window repaints automatically, it should work.