# Draw a buffered image in an applet

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet, paintcomponent

What I'm trying to do is to get an already buffered image painted to a JFrame.

```
JFrame p1=new JFrame();
p1.getContentPane();
p1.setSize(new Dimension(h,w));
p1.setVisible(true);
p1.update(bufferedImage.getGraphics());
```

This is the code so far. **bufferedImage** is a buffered image, but this code only opens the JFrame and doesn't paint the image. I've never worked with graphics before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See this working code :**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage buf=null;
    try {
        buf = ImageIO.read(new File("estbest.jpg"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    new ImageFrame(buf, "Input Image ");
}
```

**ImageFrame Class :**

```
public class ImageFrame extends JFrame {
    BufferedImage image;

    public ImageFrame(final BufferedImage image) {
        this(image, "No Title");
    }

    public ImageFrame(final BufferedImage image, final String title) {
        this.image = image;
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (image != null) {
                    setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
                } else {
                    setSize(250, 90);
                }
                setTitle(title);
                setVisible(true);
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (image == null) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 90);
            System.out.println("image null");
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawString("Invalid or No Image", 10, 50);
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Source : [Java: Loading images in JFrame - Reusable ImageFrame](http://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2011/06/java-loading-images-in-jframe-reusable.html)

Answer (score 2):

1) put [BufferedImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944388/714968) as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

2) don't paint directly to the `JFrame` put there [JComponent / JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7724971/714968)