# Java Swing resize BorderLayout.CENTER

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, border-layout

As the title says, can I redefine the height and width of Java's BorderLayout.CENTER? I plan to use Graphics2D to draw to this area but I won't always know ahead of time how big it should be to fit everything in.

Draw class (declared inside my Main class):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private class Draw extends JComponent {
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Shape drawLine = new Line2D.Float(0, 0, 500, 500);

        g.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g.draw(drawLine);
    }
}
```

Main constructor where Draw is called:

```
public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 640, 480);
    setJMenuBar(getMenuBar_1());
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    contentPane.add(getPanelControls(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    contentPane.add(getPanelInfo(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    contentPane.add(new Draw(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

I'm currently drawing directly to BorderLayout.CENTER. Should I be drawing to a JPanel and use it's setPreferredSize() method?

Comment: Yes, you can. Show your tried code.

Comment: You probably want to draw on a component in the center position instead. Then you can simply use the component's dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

> As the title says, can I redefine the height and width of Java's
>   BorderLayout.CENTER? I plan to use Graphics2D to draw to this area but
>   I won't always know ahead of time how big it should be to fit
>   everything in.

(answer only to topic)

- override its [`getPreferredSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7724971/714968)
- then any sizing are contraproductive, call `JFrame.pack();` before `JFrame.setVisible(true);`
- create a `JFrame` as local variable

EDIT

---

- override `paintComponent()` instead of `paint()`, 1st code line inside `paintComponent()` should be `super.paintComponent()`, otherwise painting cumulated
- `Shape drawLine = new Line2D.Float(0, 0, 500, 500);` should be `getHeight/Weight()` instead of  `500, 500`

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the fixed pixel at `Graphics`. Use `getHeight()` and `getWidth()` methods to get dynamic size. Use that size to draw your Line.

```
 int width=getHeight();
 int height=getHeight();

 Shape drawLine = new Line2D.Float(width/2, height/2, width/2+500, height/2+500);
```